# retrieve timestamp from postgresql with GORM in GOLANG

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am pretty new to golang and gorm so, probably, this is an old question:
I have a table in postgresql named datetime with type timestamp

I am trying to retrieve it using gorm in a golang project with this mapping

```
  DateTime time.Time `gorm:"datetime:timestamp"`
```

But when i run the code i see that it retrieves this value:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: What is the `timestamp` value in the database? `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` looks like a placeholder value for something, maybe `NULL`?

Comment: gos zero values are not nil. The zero value for a string is an empty string, boolean is false, number is 0 for example. time is that what you have there. You may want to use sql.NullTime.

Comment: To make your question clearer, then make sure people know if the record you are trying to retrieve has a non null DateTime. Also, the bad actor might be the first person who wrote that code. Are there any tests for this case? Take a look at go-sqlmock/go-mock and write a test for the code yourself.

https://github.com/golang/mock
https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock

Fail the test if the response returns a default value for timestamp instead of the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime time.Time `gorm:"datetime:timestamp;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
or
DateTime time.Time `gorm:"datetime:timestamp;default:DEFAULT"`
try this. This will store current time. In your case you are not storing any data that's why it retrieves 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was pretty simple to be honest. The field was mapped as

```
DateTime
```

which i guess is translated as "date_time" when performing the query to extract the data; so, i changed the mapping to

```
Datetime
```

which is translated to "datetime", and it worked